# ReferenceError: prisma is not defined - Next.js 14

Tags: typescript, next.js, prisma

I am using Prisma with next.js 14 and I have implemented the Stripe payment API.
this is the API I here I got error `ReferenceError: prisma is not defined` how can I fix that ?

```
import { NextApiRequest, NextApiResponse } from "next"
import { buffer } from "stream/consumers"
import Stripe from "stripe"

export const config = {
    api:{
        bodyParser: false
    }
}

const stripe = new Stripe(process.env.STRIPE_SECRET_KEY as string,{
    apiVersion: '2023-10-16'
})

export default async function handler(
    req: NextApiRequest,
    res: NextApiResponse
){

    const buf = await buffer(req)
    const sig = req.headers['stripe-signature']

    if(!sig){
        return res.status(400).send("Missing the stripe signature!")
    }

    let event: Stripe.Event

    try{
        event = stripe.webhooks.constructEvent(
            buf, sig, process.env.STRIPE_WEBHOOK_SECRET!
        )
    }catch(err){
        return res.status(400).send("Webhook error" + err)
    }

    switch(event.type){
        case 'charge.succeeded':
            const charge: any = event.data.object as Stripe.Charge;
            if(typeof charge.payment_intent === 'string'){
                await prisma?.order.update({
                    where: {paymentIntentId: charge.payment_intent},
                    data: {status: "complete", address: charge.shipping?.address},
                });
            }
            break;
        default:
            console.log("Unhandled event type:" + event.type)
    }
    res.json({received: true})
}
```

this is my folder structure.

[image]

this is the error.

```
Unhandled event type:payment_intent.succeeded
 ⨯ pages\api\stripe-webhook.ts (41:16) @ handler
 ⨯ ReferenceError: prisma is not defined
    at handler (webpack-internal:///(api)/./pages/api/stripe-webhook.ts:38:17)
    at process.processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:95:5) {       
  page: '/api/stripe-webhook'
}
  39 |             const charge: any = event.data.object as Stripe.Charge;
  40 |             if(typeof charge.payment_intent === 'string'){
> 41 |                 await prisma?.order.update({
     |                ^
  42 |                     where: {paymentIntentId: charge.payment_intent},
  43 |                     data: {status: "complete", address: charge.shipping?.address}, 
  44 |                 });
 ○ Compiling /_error ...
 ✓ Compiled /_error in 2.7s (736 modules)
```

Answer (score 1):

In your code you are not importing and instantiating `Prisma` at all.

```js
import { PrismaClient } from '@prisma/client'

const prisma = new PrismaClient();
```

See the [quickstart documentation](https://www.prisma.io/docs/getting-started/quickstart) for additional information.

Comment: When I use this DB is not updating

Comment: We would need more information to help you debug it. Is `event.type` 'charge.succeeded'?; in other words, is the update method called at all? Is `paymentIntentId` matched to a record in the database?

I would recommend logging what code path is taken and what the different variable values are.